# Inequality in $H^2,\ H^1$ and $L^\infty$

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

If

$$\|f\|_{H^{2}(0, T)} + 
\|g\|_{H^{1}(0, T ; H^{1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus[1,2]))}
+
\|g\|_{L^{\infty}(0, T ; H^{1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus[1,2]))}\leq C, \quad C\in \mathbb{R},
$$
then 
$$
\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(0, T)} + \|g\|_{L^{\infty}(0, T\times \mathbb{R}\setminus[1,2])}\leq C_1, \quad C_1\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
How can I prove this ?

Comment: Could you help me with this, please @MaoWao

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the $L^\infty$ norm in the second inequality. Should it be the same as in the first one? And is the constant in both inequalities the same?

Comment: I have made some corrections. I don't understand how in the second inequality the norms are in the spaces $ L^\infty $ @MaoWao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is again a consequence of the Sobolev embedding theorem (see Brezis. *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, Theorem 8.8): There is a constant $c>0$, depending only on $T$, such that $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq c \|f\|_{H^1}\leq c\|f\|_{H^2}$.