# Relations between $L^\infty$ and $H^2$

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I know that $H^2(0,T)\subset L^2(0,T)$, and also we know that $L^\infty(0,T)\subset L^2(0,T)$, so my question is:

Is there some relation between  $H^2(0,T)$ and $L^\infty(0,T)$, for instance:  $L^\infty(0,T)\subset H^2(0,T)?$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$L^\infty(0,T)$ is not contained in $H^2(0,T)$. As an exercise you can show that $1_{(0,T/2)}\notin H^2(0,T)$ (it is not even in $H^1$). The converse inclusion holds as a consequence of the Sobolev embedding theorem. In fact, $H^2(0,T)\subset H^1(0,T)\subset C([0,T])$.

Comment: Thanks For your help, then $L^2(0,T) \subset H^2(0,T)$ follow, is it right?

Comment: Sorry, the first sentence was nonsensical. What I wanted to write was $L^\infty\notin H^2$, which is what this example shows.

Comment: my question is about I am trying to solve this, could you help me, please [link] `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624202/inequality-in-h2-h1-and-l-infty`

Comment: Does this hold for higher dimensions? Say a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$